# making Custome UI (by extend View)

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, custom-controls, custom-component

I made CustomUI.java file

```
public class CustomUI extends View {

    Bitmap icon;
    float left=0;

    public CustomUI(Context context) {
        super(context);
        icon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, left, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
           setMeasuredDimension(250, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.getAction()==event.ACTION_SCROLL){
            left=event.getX();
        }
        if(left>=200){
            //do some activity;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I made layout custom_ui.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomUI" >

    <com.example.missedcall.CustomUI
        android:id="@+id/single_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </com.example.missedcall.CustomUI>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.missedcall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.missedcall.CustomUI"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_ui" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

when I show Graphic layout its show me well, but when I run it,
Its run n show blank layout and show error after second n close app.
Please help me to solve this problem and to make custom UI in android.

Log file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4L6o.jpg
or https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6608612/log.JPG

Comment: could it be the constructor? try without arguments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a constructor having parameter `AttributeSet` along with context in your CustomUi class.

```
public CustomUi(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    icon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
}
```

Then in your main class declare the CustomUi as

```
CustomUi customUi = (CustomUi) findViewById(R.id.single_spinner);
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.missedcall.CustomUI"
```

You need to provide the acitivity class here. I guess what you provided is Your CustomView's class

Comment: I change it as follow

<activity
            android:name="com.example.missedcall.Main"

and in Main Activity extend with Activity and
setContentView(R.layout.custom_ui);

and custom_ui.xml contain
<com.example.missedcall.CustomUI
        android:id="@+id/single_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </com.example.missedcall.CustomUI>

but still its close after a second.
Please help me to solve dis problem.

Comment: Ya now working after changing activity class in manfist and constructor of CustomUi.java file